# Updating a matplotlib canvas in PyQt5 using a Figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I need to refresh a canvas with the output of a function. Right now the function outputs a matplotlib Figure object. The problem is that when I call the method `draw` in the canvas, it doesn't show anything.

I used this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77092070/22748055)  as inspiration.

Here there is a small test script I did. The function `example_plotter` just makes a plot of random numbers. I tested it and it plots well.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
)

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas,
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar,
)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from random import randint, sample


def example_plotter(n):
    fig = Figure()
    y = sample(range(100), n)
    plt.plot(list(range(n)), y)
    return fig


class TPlotterWidget(QWidget):
    # Used this source
    # https://stackoverflow.com/q/77092070/22748055
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())

        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas.draw()

        # Add toolbar
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

        self.plotInnerLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.plotInnerLayout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        self.plotInnerLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.setLayout(self.plotInnerLayout)

    def new_figure(self):
        self.canvas.figure = example_plotter(5)
        self.canvas.draw()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")

        self.plotWidget = TPlotterWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.plotWidget)

        self.plotWidget.new_figure()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```